# VisualStateManager does not revert to original state

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, visualstatemanager, visualstates

The following definition is used as `ItemContainer` style for a `GridView`, `SelectionMode` "Single". When an element is selected, a particular glyph becomes visible to indicate selection.

It works right with Windows 8.1, but with UWP, it accepts changed state: *Selected* makes the glyph to appear, but does not revert to the original state (state *Unselected*), glyph stays with selection changed, even though `SelectionChanged` event brings the old selection as removed item.

Similar problems exist for other states (like *Pressed* and *Focused*), I just don't show the full VisualStateManager for simplicity.

```
<Style x:Key="MyItemContainerStyle" TargetType="SelectorItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="SelectorItem">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <!--  Layout of the grid  -->
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Tried also

```
<VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure your visual state group and visual states names are correct?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you've posted, it seems you are using [VisualStateGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualstategroup.aspx) and [VisualState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx)s defined in Windows 8.1. However, in UWP, these `VisualState`s have been changed.

In [GridViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx), it lists all the `VisualState`s defined in the control's default style. As you can see, in UWP, there is no "**SelectionStates**" `VisualStateGroup` and also no "**Unselected**" `VisualState`. So your code won't work in UWP.

To solve your problem, I'd suggest you rewrite your style according to the new [GridViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx) used in UWP. And in the new style, "**Normal**" and "**Selected**" visual state are in the same visual state group. So you can show "SelectingGlyph" in "Selected" and hide it in "Normal" like:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Normal">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="0"
                         Duration="0" />
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
...
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="1"
                         Duration="0" />
        ...
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```